# Clear explanation of ndigit[c - '0']

Tags: c, arrays

I've finally started to read the **K&R**, and I've just arrived to the **Array** part.
But in the example of this section, there's a piece of code I really don't understand completely, so I'd like to ask you for a clear explanation of it, as I wanna understand every concept of C as I know it's the fundamental for a fast learning of C++.

By the way I already have a decent knowledge of JAVA, hope this will help you in your explanation setup.

**Question:**

In this piece of code `ndigit[c - '0']` I don't understand what it's trying to do, I know from other Stack Overlfow questions that 0 should refer to the **ASCI** standards and should be **48**, but still **don't understand what c and that 0 have in relationship**.

Comment: A bit more context would help here. But as you said, '0' is 48 and the calculation is simple. Without context can't say anything about any relationship.

Comment: `c` is a `char`, to get the `int` value of the digit in that char you can use `c - '0'` because `'0' - '0'` is `0` and `'1' - '0'` is `1` and so on.

Comment: The ASCI**I** standard is not relevant here. In fact, this code works with all character encodings allowed for C.

Comment: Using K&R to learn C is already a bad idea. It does not even handle the previous version of the standard, even less the current. And learning C++ from K&R is just ridiculous. You would not use a Java book to learn Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said `'0'` is equal to `48` (assuming ASCII encoding). Thus the other digits are equal to `49` through `57` respectively. So `'1'` is equal to `49`, `'2'` to `50` etc. Thus `'1' - '0'` is equal to `'49 - 48'`, which is `1` and `'2' - '0'` is equal to `'50 - 48'`, which is `2` and so on.

In other words `c - '0'` converts a digit like `'5'` to its integer equivalent (which would be `5` for `'5'`).

Comment: The actual encoding is irrelevant. This is guaranteed to work for all character sets.

Comment: @Olaf All I said was that "`'0'` is equal to 48" assumes ASCII. Surely the C standard does not guarantee that `'0' == 48` even for non-ASCII encodings.

Comment: Yeah so c is a char or what?

Comment: @FET: 1) Please use markup. 2) You did not provide a [mcve], so the type of `c` is unclear. But as C does not have a _character type_, chances are good `c` is an integer type, which does include `char`. That's why `'0'` is an _**integer** character constant_

Answer (score 6):

***Short answer:***

by `ndigit[c-'0']` you are not doing normal arithmetic e.g [5+5] = [10]. Rather you are first converting your characters into character code. Then doing arithmetic with character code.

To say simply- we represent five in english with this "5" sign. Other languages have their own sign for five i.e 五 is five in japanise. Likewise Computer represent five with  53(assuming ascii, ascii is like a language). So with `ndigit[c-'0']`, its first being converted to character code then doing arithmetic.

***Long answer:***

Lets go through `ndigit[c - '0']` first.

- `ndigit` = name of the array
- `[ ]` = index, used for specifying total elements number.
- `c - '0'` = arithmetic operation. `c` is a variable. `-` is minus.And
  `'0'` is not 0 but 48.

now let me add additional code from the from the book -

```
int ndigit[10];
...//fill in the array with 0s
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')
         ++ndigit[c - '0']; //<== unable to understand this part
```

here something to note of is `getchar()`. getchar() return **int**  type data. even though it return int type but it wont return the **character** rather it will return **character code**. Let me give a example-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", c);
    }
```

output:

```
@mix:~
$ cc test.c
@mix:~
$ ./a.out
5          ;wrote 5 in terminal
53         ; printed 53 instead of 5
```

5 is the character. And 53 is the character code of 5.

Now lets back to our main topic `ndigit[c - '0']`. **c** is getting a value from `getchar()`. and getchar() reads from input. lets say the **input** is **5** . Now due to getchar() function behaviour  instead of 5, c will contain 53. So

```
ndigit[c - '0'] == `ndigit[53 - '0']` != `ndigit[5 - '0']`
```

Also notice we are not using 0. Rather '0'.
means the arithmetic -

```
    ndigit[53 - '0']
   =ndigit[53]       ;**wrong**
```

using `'0'` means we meant to use character code(used *single quote*). Like described above `'0' = 48` (according to ascii).   so

```
ndigit[53 - '0']

= ndigit[53 - 48]

= ndigit[5]
```

Now we get back our character which was read by `getchar()`. But why should we get back our character? Will `ndigit[c]` instead of `ndigit[c - '0']` work?

`ndigit[c]` wont work  because at the start of our code we wrote `ndigit[10]`  . Our `ndigit[10]` array can hold 10 elements at max. As a result `c` cant be greater than 10 or `ndigit[53]` is invalid as its size is 53 and surpassing 10  . Thats why we use `ndigit[c - '0']` to do character code subtraction and get a value under 10.

IF still unclear, search and learn about the following-

1. charater encoding
2. array in c

Answer (score 1):

In this code `c` is a `char`, presumably representing a digit. In C a `char` is an integral type, so you can perform arithmetic operations on them.

Digits are encoded with numbers from a consecutive range: if the code for `'0'` is `k`, the code for `'1'` is `k+1`, the code for `'2'` is `k+2`, and so on. That is why by subtracting `'0'` from a character representing a digit you get the numeric value of that digit.

For example, by subtracting `'5'-'0'` you get a numeric `5` instead of character `'5'`.

If you make an array `ndigit[10]`, then `ndigit[c - '0']` lets you access an array element corresponding to the digit. This can be used, for example, to count the number of different digits in the input.